# Is there a way to save state of a DataTable across different html pages?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

I'm working with Bootstrap's responsive dataTables.
I'm aware that there is a stateSave option, but I'm wondering if there is a way to save the filtering state of a dataTable when I load it on different html pages?

What I'm doing is I'm initializing the datatable in a common JS file. And I have different html pages linked to each other, each with a datatable with the same ID written into them. 
After I sort the table on one page and press on the link to the other, is there a way for the table to stay in the same state with the filtered data?

Thanks!

Comment: how about pass the same filters of the first datatable within the button link url? Then your server could generate a result based on these filters.

Comment: Thanks--it worked. Although in the end I went with localStorage since I wanted to bind what I wanted to do with an event.